# Access to fetch at 'https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, cors, cloudflare

How do i fix this?

```
let response = await fetch("https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace", {
    // credentials: 'include',
    method: 'GET',
    // method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
})
```

> Access to fetch at 'https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace' from
> origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Request header field content-type is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: Recommended way would be do it via backend and return the response locally. Not in frontend.

Comment: if i get the ip from backend, will it return the backend IP instead?

Answer (score 5):

You can try do it like this:

```js
async function test () {
  let response = await fetch("https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace", {mode: "cors"});
  let text = await response.text();
  console.log(text)
}
test()
```

Comment: and check your json, is it valid?

Comment: @phongyewtong Glad it helped. On stackoverflow you can say "thank you" by accepting the answer that helped you. :)