# How can i get a client side cookie with next.js 13 before rendering from middleware

Tags: node.js, cookies, next.js, middleware

I am trying to get a cookie from the middleware of Nextjs 13 and I can't find up to date information on this.

My question: is there a way to see the cookie before rendering the html.

window is fined or something?

page.tsx

```
async function getData() {
    const nextCookies = cookies(); // Get cookies object

    try {
        let cityToken = nextCookies.get('regionCode'); // Find cookie city
        return cityToken;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}


export default async function Page() {
   const nextCookies = cookies(); // Get cookies object
   const token = nextCookies.get('new'); // Find cookie for is new user
        
   // const cityToken = await getData();
   const cityToken = cookies().get('regionCode')?.value;
        
   console.log(cityToken);
        
}
```

middleware.tsx

```
const myFunction = async () => {
    // https://geolocation.onetrust.com/cookieconsentpub/v1/geo/location
    // run asynchronous tasks here - ip location
    const response = await fetch('https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace');
    const text = await response.text();
    const arr = text.split('\n');
    const ip = arr.filter((v) => v.includes('ip='))[0].split('=')[1];

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752416/how-can-i-most-easily-parse-this-http-response-into-json-to-then-access-response
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64591296/access-to-fetch-at-https-www-cloudflare-com-cdn-cgi-trace-from-origin-http

    const ipCity = await fetch(`https://ipapi.co/${ip}/json/`);

    const textJson = await ipCity.json();
};
const data = await myFunction();
res.cookies.set('regionCode', 'textJson.region');
```